# Where to write pure python code in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have learned the basics of Django. I would like to make a website with 4 calculators and my question is where to put pure python code responsible for all calculations(like all functions and math)? Should I write my calculator in views.py or create new file for example calcA.py ?
I am asking because I would like to learn good practice of writting projects in Django.

My concept is for each calculator I will make app so for 4 calculators I will make 4 apps. In each app folder I will create models.py which is kind of sketch/outline that will be placed in templates. In each app folder, in views.py I will write calculators using python. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ok to put your calculators' logic into `views.py`

Comment: @memo747 glad to help :) all the best!

Answer (score -1):

```
 c = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): "))   
 # Check if choice is one of the four options  
 if (c > 4):     
     print("Invalid input") 
 elif (c == 1):     
     a = int(input("Enter first number: "))     
     b = int(input("Enter second number: "))     
     print(a,"+",b,"=", add(a,b)) 
 elif (c == 2):     
     a = int(input("Enter first number: "))     
     b = int(input("Enter second number: "))     
     print(a,"-",b,"=", subtract(a,b)) 
 elif (c == 3):     
     a = int(input("Enter first number: "))     
     b = int(input("Enter second number: "))     
     print(a,"*",b,"=", multiply(a,b)) 
 elif (c == 4):     
     a = int(input("Enter first number: "))     
     b = int(input("Enter second number: "))     
     print(a,"/",b,"=", divide(a,b))
```